# Trace AT commands to a modem

Tags: modem, cellular-internet, at

I have a HSDPA modem attached to the USB port and I use the software that came bundled up with this modem to connect to the Internet. Can I trace the AT commands issued to this modem using a packet capture tool like wireshark.

Comment: 1) No, because serial port traffic is not network packets; 2) Which operating system? On Windows you can enable "Log file" in the modem device properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what you want is achievable with http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/ . And if your modem creates a virtual com port(quite possible) then you could use program to sniff RS232 like http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/